# multiple vue instances from for loop

Tags: .net, vue.js, razor

i'm trying to create multiple vue instances dynamically, I can get the instances to mount but they are not bound to the html, v-model and v-on:change are not working

```
  Init() {
    var elements = document.querySelectorAll('[id^="training-product-app"]');
    for (let index = 0; index < elements.length; index++) {
      const id = elements[index].id;
      this.startApp(id);
    }
  }
  startApp(elementId) {

    const data = {};
    const methods = {};
    const watch = {};
    const el = `#${elementId}`;

    
    const instance = new Vue({i18n, el, data, methods, watch,  // jshint ignore:line
      created() {
        this.$nextTick(() => {
          this.$mount(`#${elementId}`);
        });
      }
    });
    console.log('instance     ',instance);
```

all of this works when I have a single instance, the error is in the loop somewhere

```
 <div id="training-product-app-@productIndex" >
                                        @Html.Partial("~/Views/Commerce/Product/TrainingVariantsForm.cshtml", new ProductPageFormViewModel
  {
   VariantDetails = item,
   VariantType = method.Value.ToAlphaOnly(),
  })
</div>
```

I would have thought that the $nextTick would mean that all html had loaded before the vue instance was mounted, so I can't understand why it wouldn't be bound

update:

if I write dynamic property on data, call it 'name' and have its value be 'elementId' - I can see that this will be rendered in the DOM correctly on load. There seems to be nothing wrong with the data, its just the methods that aren't working

Comment: `$mount` only works when the `el` option hasn't been passed in the Vue instance. So first I would try to remove the `el` from the option parameter :)

Comment: I tried it with both, just using el and also just using mount. I'vee also tried js ways like window.load and document.ready to ensure the necessary html is there before mounting.